# JAXB: how to unmarshal a List of objects of different types but with common parent?

Tags: java, jaxb

There is a fairly common pattern in our applications.  We configure a configure a set (or list) of  objects in Xml, which all implement a common interface.  On start-up, the application reads the Xml and uses JAXB to create/configure a List of objects. I have never figured out (after reading various posts many times) the "right way" to do this using only JAXB.

For example, we have an interface `Fee`, and multiple concrete implementing classes which have some common properties, as well as some diverging properties, and very different behaviors. The Xml we use to configure the List of Fees used by application is:

```
<fees>
   <fee type="Commission" name="commission" rate="0.000125" />
   <fee type="FINRAPerShare" name="FINRA" rate="0.000119" />
   <fee type="SEC" name="SEC" rate="0.0000224" />
   <fee type="Route" name="ROUTES">
       <routes>
        <route>
            <name>NYSE</name>
            <rates>
                <billing code="2" rate="-.0014" normalized="A" />
                <billing code="1" rate=".0029" normalized="R" />
            </rates>
        </route>        
        </routes>
          ...
    </fee>
  </fees>
```

In the above Xml, each `<fee>` element corresponds to a concrete subclass of a Fee interface.  The `type` attribute gives information about which type to instantiate, and then once it is instantiated, the JAXB unmarshalling applies the properties from the remaining Xml.

I always have to resort to doing something like this:

```
private void addFees(TradeFeeCalculator calculator) throws Exception {
    NodeList feeElements = configDocument.getElementsByTagName("fee");
    for (int i = 0; i < feeElements.getLength(); i++) {
        Element feeElement = (Element) feeElements.item(i);
        TradeFee fee = createFee(feeElement);
        calculator.add(fee);
    }
}

private TradeFee createFee(Element feeElement) {
    try {
        String type = feeElement.getAttribute("type");
        LOG.info("createFee(): creating TradeFee for type=" + type);
        Class<?> clazz = getClassFromType(type);
        TradeFee fee = (TradeFee) JAXBConfigurator.createAndConfigure(clazz, feeElement);
        return fee;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Trade Fees are misconfigured, xml which caused this=" + XmlUtils.toString(feeElement), e);
    }
}
```

In the above code, the `JAXBConfigurator` is just a simple wrapper around the JAXB objects for unmarshalling:

```
public static Object createAndConfigure(Class<?> clazz, Node startNode) {
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        JAXBElement configElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(startNode, clazz);
        return configElement.getValue();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

At the end, of the above code, we get a List which contains whichever types were configured in the Xml.

Is there a way to get JAXB to do this automatically without having to write the code to iterate the elements as above?

Comment: can you alter the xml format or do you have to work with it as is?

Comment: @jtahlborn: The Xml can be anything that is easy to hand-edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

If you are using MOXy as your JAXB provider then you could use the MOXy's `@XmlPaths` annotation to extend the standard JAXB `@XmlElements` annotation to do the following:

**Fees**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Fees {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(type=Commission.class),
        @XmlElement(type=FINRAPerShare.class),
        @XmlElement(type=SEC.class),
        @XmlElement(type=Route.class)
    })
    @XmlPaths({
        @XmlPath("fee[@type='Commission']"),
        @XmlPath("fee[@type='FINRAPerShare']"),
        @XmlPath("fee[@type='SEC']"),
        @XmlPath("fee[@type='Route']")
    })
    private List<Fee> fees;

}
```

**Commission**

The implementations of the `Fee` interface would be annotated normally.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Commission implements Fee {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String rate;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the above a try.

Comment: Is there any chance that JAXB will enhance the factoryMethod feature to take an argument which passes in the current Xml element, so that instancing the object could be handled via Reflection?

Comment: Thanks again for the example.  I learned quite a bit from it. In the end, I just used XmlElements annotation, and varied the Xml tag name for each concrete subtype. Of course, it would be nicer if you could just add a new concrete subtype in the code, update the Xml, and not have to update the binding annotation... :)

Comment: @SamGoldberg - Did you check out the `@XmlElementRef` annotation?  It can be used to model the concept of substitution groups in XML Schema:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Answer (score 4):

You could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.  The impl bleow handles just the `Commission` type but could be easily extended to support all the types.  You need to ensure that `AdaptedFee` contains the combined properties from all the implementations of the `Fee` interface.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class FeeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<FeeAdapter.AdaptedFee, Fee>{

    public static class AdaptedFee {

        @XmlAttribute
        public String type;

        @XmlAttribute
        public String name;

        @XmlAttribute
        public String rate;

    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedFee marshal(Fee fee) throws Exception {
        AdaptedFee adaptedFee = new AdaptedFee();
        if(fee instanceof Commission) {
            Commission commission = (Commission) fee;
            adaptedFee.type = "Commission";
            adaptedFee.name = commission.name;
            adaptedFee.rate = commission.rate;
        }
        return adaptedFee;
    }

    @Override
    public Fee unmarshal(AdaptedFee adaptedFee) throws Exception {
        if("Commission".equals(adaptedFee.type)) {
            Commission commission = new Commission();
            commission.name = adaptedFee.name;
            commission.rate = adaptedFee.rate;
            return commission;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

An `XmlAdapter` is configured using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Fees {

    @XmlElement(name="fee")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FeeAdapter.class)
    private List<Fee> fees;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

Comment: Thanks also for this suggestion. I have plumbed your blog many times to look for different ways of doing things with JAXB!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible if all the elements are named `<fee>`. Even if it were(or is) it would be very confusing from maintenance point of view.

Do you have the ability to rename various fee elements based on type (e.g. `<tradeFee>` instead of `<fee>`)?

Otherwise you can create a `BaseFee` class that has all the fields for every possible type of `<fee>`. You can unmarshall data into a list of `BaseFee` objects and convert them into a more specific type at runtime, e.g.

```
List<BaseFee> fees = ...;
for (BaseFee fee : fees) {
    if (isTradeFee(fee)) {
        TradeFee tradeFee = toTradeFee(fee);
        // do something with trade fee...
    }
}
```

A bit of a hack but given the requirements it should do the job.

Comment: The xml can be whatever makes it easy for user's to hand-edit, but also works with JAXB.