# JAXB unmarshalling xml both @XmlValue and @XmlElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Hi I am unmarshalling a XML file that has a tag that can contain both a value or a list of elements. I was wondering what the best approach is for unmarshalling this kind of XML. Example:

```
<attributes>
    <attribute>value1</attribute>
    <attribute>value2</attribute>
    <attribute>value3</attribute>
    <attribute>value4</attribute>
    <attribute>
        <value>value11</value>
        <value>value12</value>
        <value>value13</value>
        <value>value14</value>
        <value>value15</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>value5</attribute>
    <attribute>value6</attribute>
</attributes>
```

I can't change the way of how the XML is build up so I am hoping someone has a answer. Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078566/jaxb-how-to-unmarshal-a-list-of-objects-of-different-types-but-with-common-pare ?

Comment: I think you'll need to write a custom adapter because you have no discriminator in your XML sample that allows to automatically find the type of an `attribute` element (i.e. list or simple).

Answer (score 2):

Basic steps to read-write xml using `JaxB` / [`Unmarshaller`](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) and `XSD`

- Create a **valid** `XSD` file of your `XML` structure. [Find here an online generator.](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html)

  Will be something like this (*but maybe you need to modify manually some detail, in your XML structure seems you can create the `Attribute` class wrapping several `<attribute>` but I dont know for sure if you can have more than one `<attributes>` tag*):

  ```
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="attributes">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="attribute" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  ```
- Place it in your project folder.
- Right click `XSD` file and [auto-generate JAXB classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23917101/3850595).
- Use [`Unmarshaller`](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html) to populate auto-generated classes from XML file:

  ```
  Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
  Attributes attributes = (Attributes) u.unmarshal( new FileInputStream( "yourFile.xml" ) );
  ```

That's it... JaxB will take care of classes, attributes, populate, write/read xml...

Comment: I'm curious of what JAXB will generate for a XSD that matches Chris's XML sample. Not sure JAXB can handle unmarshalling without a custom adapter or specific code (no `xsi:type` on `attribute` elements for instance..).

Comment: @Gaël if you read my answer I warn OP about that, I just put the xsd resulting of an automatic building, what helps, but almost never is perfect for concrete needings.