# JAXB : Create Instance of class based on attribute value

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

If I have the following xml.

```
<tag type="div" class="parent">
      <children>
            <tag type="span"/>
            <tag type="div"/>
      </children>
</tag>
```

Along with it I have following class

```
public abstract class Tag {
      @XmlAttribute( "class" )
      private String classes;

      private List<Tag> children;
}
```

And some implementing classes like :

```
public class Span extends Tag {
}

public class Button extends Tag {
}
```

An element string `<tag type="div" class="parent">` can be translated to its implementing class using attribute value of `type`.

Is there a way I can configure JAXB to create instances of Tag class depending upon an element string's type attribute value ?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the answer is here : [JAXB: how to unmarshal a List of objects of different types but with common parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078566/jaxb-how-to-unmarshal-a-list-of-objects-of-different-types-but-with-common-pare)

You need to use EclipseLink moxy on top of JAXB: org.eclipse.persistence.moxy. You will get the @XmlPaths the example refers to.